# Combining enum values and checking if another value is in that enum

Tags: typescript, enums

Consider the following code:

```
enum myEnum {
    a = 1,
    b = 2
}

enum mySecondEnum {
    c = 3,
    d = 4
}

enum myThirdEnum {
    e = 5,
    f = 6
}

/** This is an array, that should contain numbers from 1 to 4 - instead, it also contains the string keys of the enums - is there a way to limit this array to only */
const enumValuesArray = [...Object.values(myEnum), ...Object.values(mySecondEnum)];
console.log(enumValuesArray);

/** Here, b can be a number from 1 to 6 */
const b: myEnum | mySecondEnum | myThirdEnum = 5;


/** Why is typescript complaining here? I understand, that b CAN be 5 or 6 (as it is), but that is exactly the thing I want to check */
if (enumValuesArray.includes(b)) {
    console.log("Included");
} else console.log("Not included");
```

While this code compiles and runs as expected, TypeScript complains when I am trying to check if the output array includes the value of "b". The error message I am getting is as follows:

> Argument of type 'myEnum | mySecondEnum | myThirdEnum' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | myEnum | mySecondEnum'.
> Type 'myThirdEnum.e' is not assignable to type 'string | myEnum | mySecondEnum'.(2345)

How should I resolve this error?

As a second note, is it possible somehow, to retrieve an array of enum values only, instead of enum values and properties?

Comment: Enum is bidirectional data structure. What are you expect from `.Object.values(myEnum)` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, it worth using immutable object instead of numerical enums.
See example:

```js
const myEnum = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
} as const

const mySecondEnum = {
    c: 3,
    d: 4
} as const

const myThirdEnum = {
    e: 5,
    f: 6
} as const
```

Now, `enumValuesArray` has an expected type:

```js
// (1 | 2 | 3 | 4)[]
const enumValuesArray = [...Object.values(myEnum), ...Object.values(mySecondEnum)];
```

As for the error with `Array.prototype.includes`. It is known issue. TS only allows you to use numbers which are exists in `enumValuesArray`.

There is a generic and a little bit verbose workaround.
Pros: no need type assertion
Cons: verbose and requires you to curry.

Full example:

```js
const myEnum = {
    a: 1,
    b: 2
} as const

const mySecondEnum = {
    c: 3,
    d: 4
} as const

const myThirdEnum = {
    e: 5,
    f: 6
} as const

type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type Primitives =
    | string
    | number
    | bigint
    | boolean
    | symbol
    | null
    | undefined

type InferPrimitive<T, P> = P extends any ? T extends P ? P : never : never;

type Inference<T> = InferPrimitive<T, Primitives>


const withTuple = <
    List extends Primitives[]
>(list: readonly [...List]) =>
    (prop: Inference<List[number]>):
        prop is Inference<List[number]> & List[number] =>
        list.includes(prop)


// (1 | 2 | 3 | 4)[]
const enumValuesArray = [...Object.values(myEnum), ...Object.values(mySecondEnum)];

const includes = withTuple(enumValuesArray);

type DistributeValues<T> = T extends any ? Values<T> : never

// 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6
type AllowedValues = DistributeValues<typeof myEnum | typeof mySecondEnum | typeof myThirdEnum>


/** Here, b can be a number from 1 to 6 */
const b: AllowedValues = 5; // ok


/** Why is typescript complaining here? I understand, that b CAN be 5 or 6 (as it is), but that is exactly the thing I want to check */
if (includes(b)) {
    console.log("Included");
} else console.log("Not included");

includes('a') // expected error
```

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/mpgQaN)

More explanation regarding `includes` you will find in my [article](https://catchts.com/useful-patterns#includes)

`InferPrimitive` - will unnnarow literal type to much wider type. For instance `InferPrimitive<42>` will return `number`.